# Complex model relationships compared to writing methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, model-associations

I am adding a voting and karma/reputation system (similar to here, HN, etc.) for an app and have decided to make my own as none of the existing gems had all the features I wanted. While working on the basic functionality I ended up writing some pretty complex associations in my models, and am unsure how this compares to say, writing my own methods (or scopes) to return the same data.

Pseudo-code below. (Users can Vote on Questions and Answers, but Users also have upvotes and downvotes through Q/A that they've posted)

```
User
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers
  has_many :votes

  has_many :question_up_votes, through: :questions, source: :vote, 
            conditions: {voteable_type: :question, 'score > 0'}

  has_many :question_down_votes, through: :questions, source: :vote, 
            conditions: {voteable_type: :question, 'score < 0'}

  has_many :answer_up_votes, through: :answers, source: :vote, 
            conditions: {voteable_type: :answer, 'score > 0'}

  has_many :answer_down_votes, through: :answers, source: :vote, 
            conditions: {voteable_type: :answer, 'score < 0'}


Question
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions
  has_many :votes, as: :voteable


Answer
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :votes, as: :voteable


Vote
  belongs_to :voter, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user, through: :voteable

  attr_accessible :score, :user_id, :voteable_type, :voteable_id
```

Specifically, for the four complex associations in the User model, would it be better performance, less error-prone, or have other advantages to write some methods (or scopes) that return the same information, either in the User model or the Q/A models?

I'm very new to Rails (and programming) and this is my first Stack Overflow question, so gentleness appreciated. Let me know if this question is a better fit for a different Stack property. Thanks!

Comment: This is an excellent question that I can't figure out either.